# CloudForms and Openshift

Tags: openshift

I have a generic question here and I have just started using Openshift enterprise and Origin but I would like to know the details on Cloudforms UI, I know that CloudForms UI can do a lot of things including managing Openshift instances but I would like to know the following in terms of managing Openshift instance, can CloudForms be able to do the following :

1. Order New Openshift environments[For ex, DEV, UAT and PROD], where I could say how many nodes and other details I need for those environments?
2. Could I be able to plug-in custom tools like ELK/Splunk or AppDynamics to the ordered environments as part of provisioning or later?
3. Could I be able to populate locally build images and publish it to all the users for using them? For ex: Suppose my middleware teams build images for Tomcat, Nginx etc and they could be able to publish it in CloudForm and I could be able to add them to my newly ordered environments through the Cloudforms UI, could this be done?
4. Could I add multiple registries and integrate them with my ordered environments.
5. Does it have all the features that Openshift Enterprise console has? like scanling, S2i etc.
6. Could I promote my images from one environment to other through the Cloudforms UI?
7. Can I integrate CI/CD tools and build environments with my ordered environments?
8. The RBAC in CloudForms can it be modified and catered to suit my requirements/ could this be customized to suit any firms needs?
9. Could I replicate my DEV openshift ENV to UAT and then to PROD environments? I did see replicators tab in the videos.
10. Can a charge back model be implemented in the Cloudforms UI ? if its already there then could be customized?

What I am trying to find here is to see if CloudForms can provide an end to end Openshift solution. The end user must only have his/her code ready, rest everything could be within the UI.

Kindly let me know what all are possible and what all are not.

Answer (score 1):

CloudForms is not trying to substitute OpenShift UI, but complement it, giving you more information about the environment and providing additional capabilities on top of OPenShift.

You can see information about what is being done and demos in videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVLo9Nc_10E&list=PLQAAGwo9CYO-4tQsnC6oWgzhPNOykOOMd&index=15

And you can find the presentations here
http://www.slideshare.net/ManageIQ/presentations

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergio :). But what is Manage IQ is it an enhanced CloudForms UI from Red Hat that takes care of everything that I mentioned above or is it another vendor? Please let me know.

Comment: ManageIQ is the upstream version of CloudForms.

Or CloudForms is the product that you can get from Red Hat that is the result of adding support, QA, training, etc to the code in ManageIQ.

The same that RHEL is downstream from Fedora, or JBOSS from WildFly

Comment: Thanks Sergio for quick response.